# Modify json with GSON without using a POJO

Tags: java, json, gson

I want to modify a json content without converting it into a POJO. I am using GSON Library.

Following are the use case:

```
String jsonString = "[{\"key1\":\"Hello\",\"key2\":\"World\"},{\"key1\":\"Nice\",\"key2\":\"Town\"}]";

JsonElement jsonElement = gson.fromJson(jsonString, JsonElement.class);
```

Is there any way where I can set value of key1 to some value (let say "Test") in each array, without converting things into POJO

Answer (score 17):

Here's the shortest I came up with.

```
JsonElement je = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, JsonElement.class);
JsonObject jo = je.getAsJsonObject();
jo.add("key", value);
```

Once you have the JsonObject, gson has many methods to manipulate it.

Comment: can you please post complete solution, I didn't understand how is gson object created ?

Answer (score 3):

You can always get a different type than JsonElement, or use JsonElement.getAsJsonObject to cast to an Object (if possible).

```
String jsonString = "[{\"key1\":\"Hello\",\"key2\":\"World\"}, ...]";

JsonArray jsonArray = gson.fromJson(jsonString, JsonElement.class).getAsJsonArray();
JsonObject firstObject = jsonArray.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
firstObject.addProperty("key1", "Test");
```

I was wrong earlier; there seems to be no JsonArray adapter; you'll have to get a JsonElement and use the casting tool.

Comment: Upvote for the array solution. Please update the loop in your answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to just convert the JSON to a `java.util.Map`, modify the Map, and go from there (which may mean serializing the Map back to JSON).

This approach meets my preference to work with the right API for the right job, minimizing the use of tools like Gson to just handle serialization/deserialization (which is what I understand it was designed for).  That is, to not use the Gson API as a replacement data structure.

Comment: How would you convert JSON to Map?

Answer (score 0):

GSON has two separate APIs (that can be combined): one is used for serialization and deserialization, and the other for streaming. If you want to process streams of JSON without memory overhead or using dynamic structures (rather than static POJOs) you can do something like:

- create a JsonWriter (in my example I use StringWriter);
- create a JsonReader;
- make a loop that consumes events from the reader and feeds them to the writer, possibly making changes, additions, omissions etc.

The loop will consist of a single switch statement that must have a case all the possible events (10 of them). Even the simplest example must have all of them, so the code below looks rather verbose. But it is very easy to extend and further extensions will not make it much longer.

An example that appends "test": 1 pair to each object looks something like:

```
public class Whatever {

static void streamandmodify(JsonReader reader, JsonWriter writer) throws IOException {
    while (true) {
        JsonToken token = reader.peek();
        switch (token) {
        // most cases are just consume the event
        // and pass an identical one to the writer
        case BEGIN_ARRAY:
            reader.beginArray();
            writer.beginArray();
            break;
        case END_ARRAY:
            reader.endArray();
            writer.endArray();
            break;
        case BEGIN_OBJECT:
            reader.beginObject();
            writer.beginObject();

            // this is where the change happens:
            writer.name("test");
            writer.value(1);
            break;
        case END_OBJECT:
            reader.endObject();
            writer.endObject();
            break;
        case NAME:
            String name = reader.nextName();
            writer.name(name);
            break;
        case STRING:
            String s = reader.nextString();
            writer.value(s);
            break;
        case NUMBER:
            String n = reader.nextString();
            writer.value(new BigDecimal(n));
            break;
        case BOOLEAN:
            boolean b = reader.nextBoolean();
            writer.value(b);
            break;
        case NULL:
            reader.nextNull();
            writer.nullValue();
            break;
        case END_DOCUMENT:
            return;
        }
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // just for test:
    JsonReader jr = new JsonReader(new StringReader("{\"a\":1, \"b\":{\"c\":[1,2,3,{},{}]}}"));
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    JsonWriter jw = new JsonWriter(sw);
    streamandmodify(jr, jw);
    System.out.println(sw.getBuffer().toString());
}
}
```

Comment: Nice example of what JsonWriter can do, that's for sure. But for OP's task, there is no reason why to re-create the JSON object by streaming instead of using well-tested gson.fromJson(). See Jeff's answer.

Comment: @teejay: "no reason"? how would you know? why such comment? I can find some pretty good reasons for NOT building an entire in-memory representation of an arbitrarily large JSON document just to add a some properties and, say, serialize the whole thing back to a file. Neither of us knows the context of the question, so both streamish and domish approach seems might be better.

Comment: Well, I assume that people comming to this page want to solve their problem - that is to modify JSON from string that is already fully available to them (= no reason for streaming). Your answer "works" but would be more appropriate in another context. No offense :)

Comment: @teejay: I understand that you are the voice of "the people"? And somehow read the exact context of the question from the author's mind? Well, in such case - I am sorry for writing such an answer, it won't happen again. But allow me to defend myself: in the strange land where I live, Java applications use JSON mainly to communicate with external systems, using network or files. The exotic versions of java.io and javax.servlet packages that I use include few methods that make data just pop into memory as Strings, and this forces me to work with streams. I really, really thought I wasn't alone.

Comment: I see you are the streaming guy:) We just assuming different contexts "by default", that's OK. Just wonder what are cons of this approach.. have u ever had some problems with performance? Or with output JSON invalidity? Have you Unit tested? What about migrating to newer GSON versions, is it at least a bit future-proof?

Answer (score 0):

The jsonString is a plain, ordinary Java String; so you can modify it whatever you like using the standards String functions of Java and replace the substring `key1` with `Test1`:

```
jsonString = "[{\"key1\":\"Test\",\"key2\":\"World\"},{\"key1\":\"Nice\",\"key2\":\"Town\"}]";
```

Of course, String in Java are immutable so converting it first to a StringBuilder will possibly give you a better performance in term of memory usage.

Comment: This is a decent-if-hacky strategy in test code, but be careful in production if either the original or string or replacement is user-supplied. JavaScript (and JSON by extension) is pretty complicated in its handling of escapes and special characters. You probably want to let a well-tested library edit your JSON in production.

Comment: Probably you have got the question wrong. I am interested in modifying the value of key1 and not key1 itself. So in first case, the Value of key1 is Hello, which I wished to modify.

Comment: Oh, the answer remains the same; it's only the example that must be changed.

Comment: I think, its no point in further discussing. If your answer remains the same, then I can't manage dynamic values, which could be anything, without me knowing what to replace with what and when.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the Java's string functions nor with the json format but this shouldn't be a major problem for anyone. For example, you could search for bot the subtring "key1":" and ,"key2" (including the comma and the quotes); knowing that you must replace what's between them or you could search for "key1":" and then scan every character until your find the terminal double quote ", taking into account that any embedded double quote will be preceded by the escape character \. The solution will depend on the complexity of your jsontString but only you know about this parameter.

Comment: This is bad idea. very bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Modify json with GSON JsonArray Java 8

Example of how to use GSON to modify a value within a JSON

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

public class ModifyJson {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String data = "[{\"ct_pk\":24,\"ct_name\":\"SISTEMA DE PRUEBAS\"},"
                + "{\"ct_pk\":1,\"ct_name\":\"CAPITAL FEDERAL\"}," +
                "{\"ct_pk\":5,\"ct_name\":\"SISTEMA DE PRUEBAS DOS\"}]";

        System.out.println("before................." + data);

        JsonArray jsonArray = new Gson().fromJson(data, JsonElement.class).getAsJsonArray();
        JsonArray jsonArray2 = new JsonArray();
        for (JsonElement pa : jsonArray) {
            JsonObject jsonObject2 = pa.getAsJsonObject();
            String ct_name = jsonObject2.get("ct_name").getAsString();
            if (ct_name.equals("SISTEMA DE PRUEBAS")) {
                jsonObject2.addProperty("ct_name", "TODOS");
            }
            jsonArray2.add(jsonObject2);
        }
        System.out.println("after.................." +jsonArray2);
    }
}
```